# Как осуществить проверку с разными входными параметрами

Tags: python, pytest

Пытаюсь через параметризацию сделать два теста с разными входными параметрами.

```
post_json_video_with_text_teg_game_inGameId = {
        'text': '@sokoban TEST POST VIDEO MP4',
        'gameId': '2',
        'inGameId': '245245'
}

post_json_video_with_text_teg = {
        'text': '@sokoban TEST POST VIDEO MP4'
}

@pytest.mark.parametrize('files, data',
                         [(video_foot, post_json_video_with_text_teg_game_inGameId),
                          (video_foot, post_json_video_with_text_teg)]) 
def test_create_video_posts_2(files, data):
    request_post_create = PostController().create_post(files=files, data=data)
    teg = request_post_create['body']['text']
    in_game_id = request_post_create['body']['inGameId']
    game_id = request_post_create['body']['game']['id']
    file_type = request_post_create['body']['files'][0]['fileType']
    if request_post_create['body']['inGameId'] == '245245' and request_post_create['body']['game']['id'] == 2:
        assert in_game_id == '245245'
        assert game_id == 2
        assert file_type == "VIDEO"
        assert request_post_create['status']['statusCodeValue'] == 200
    else:
        assert request_post_create['status']['statusCodeValue'] == 200
               and teg == '@sokoban TEST POST VIDEO MP4'
```

Но по всей видимости делаю, что то не так, так как проходит первый тест успешно, а второй нет

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('files, data',
                             [(video_foot, post_json_video_with_text_teg_game_inGameId),
                              (video_foot, post_json_video_with_text_teg)])
    def test_create_video_posts_2(files, data):
        request_post_create = PostController().create_post(files=files, data=data)
>       in_game_id = request_post_create['body']['inGameId']
E       TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

В тесте вы обращаетесь к ключу 'inGameId'

```
in_game_id = request_post_create['body']['inGameId']
```

В первом параметре (post_json_video_with_text_teg_game_inGameId) этот ключ есть, а во втором (post_json_video_with_text_teg).
Поэтому первый тест проходит успешно, а во втором, при попытке получить 'inGameId', падает ошибка об отсутствии ключа inGameId в словаре